# Too much vertical space before \part when using \marginpar

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, marginpar

When I use a `\marginpar{...}` before `\part{...}` on a new page, I get a big space on the top of that page. Below is a screenshot, where the left one was typeset with `marginpar`, the right one without:

[image: screenshot]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}

% too much space before part:
\marginpar{Lorem\\Ipsum}
\part{Lorem Ipsum Dolor}
\lipsum[5]
\pagebreak

% without marginpar
\part{Lorem Ipsum Dolor}
\lipsum[5]
\pagebreak

% marginpar after part (not possible for me):
% everythink ok, no vertical spacing
\part{Lorem Ipsum Dolor}
\marginpar{Lorem\\Ipsum}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

I have the same problems with the `marginnote`-package.

If I put the `\marginpar` after the `\part`-command, everything works fine – but this is not possible for me.
(I `\input`/`\include` the parts and the marginpars show the filename and some information for that file.)

Is it possible to remove all the space above a `\part`?

**Edit** - some additionally information

I need this for lecture notes. I have one main file `lecture.tex` which inputs every lecture from a separate .tex-file (`2013-05-08.tex`, `2013-05-10.tex` etc). Before every `\input`, I want to display the date ( = the filename) and the number of the lecture ( = a counter) using `\marginpar`. Everything works as expected, but when the external file begins with a `\part` (a new chapter in the lecture), I get this supplementary space. Not every lecture begins with a new chapter.
I wanted to keep my question as general as possible, that's because I haven't written this before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For aligning the marginpar to "Part I", do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\origpartname\partname
\newcommand{\partmargin}[2]{%
 % #1 = part title
 % #2 = margin par
 \expandafter\def\expandafter\partname\expandafter{\partname
   \marginpar{#2}}%
 \part{#1}
 \let\partname\origpartname
}    

\begin{document}

\partmargin{Lorem Ipsum Dolor}{Lorem\\Ipsum}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to David Carlisle for having spotted a weakness.

---

A simple solution for your more complex problem can be as follows. I use `filecontents` to provide two mock lecture files. So long as your files begin with plain text and not lists such as `enumerate`, this should work.

```
\begin{filecontents}{2013-05-08.tex}
\part{Start}

\section{Something}
This is the first lecture
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{2013-05-09.tex}
\section{What's here?}

This is the second lecture.
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{lecturecount}
\newcommand{\lectureinput}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{lecturecount}%
  \everypar={\marginpar{#1\\Lecture \thelecturecount}\everypar={}}%
  \input{#1}\par
}


\begin{document}

\lectureinput{2013-05-08}
\lectureinput{2013-05-09}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you want this to avoid putting the heading in a group (note the indentation) `\newcommand{\partmargin}[2]{%
 % #1 = part title
 % #2 = margin par
\let\oldpartname\parname
 \expandafter\def\expandafter\partname\expandafter{\partname
   \marginpar{#2}}%
 \part{#1}%
\let\partname\oldparname
}`

Comment: Although this works perfectly, it is not suitable for my setup: I input many external files and not every one is starting with a `\part`, but each one gets a `\marginpar`.

Comment: @ralfix You should make it clear in your question. It's impossible to answer questions you don't make.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I wanted to keep my question as general as possible. I'm sorry for your effort, but I learned a lot, and would like to thank you for that.

Comment: Thank you, your edit is what I was looking for. However, if the external file begins with a `\paragraph`, the marginpars are not shown?

Comment: @ralfix `\paragraph` fights with the setting of `\everypar`, probably; I'll try to solve the issue. But I've never felt the need to go at the fourth sectional level.